# How to solve scroll down problem in CSS Layout

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm not an expert in CSS, and I having some trouble with a template. The problem is in the scroll down. I can't put them correctly across all the template.

I have the full code of the template here. Just copy/paste and will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> stu nicholls | CSS PLaY | cross browser fixed header/footer layout basic method </title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #printhead {display:none;}

    html {
        height:100%; 
        max-height:100%; 
        padding:0; 
        margin:0; 
        border:0; 
        background:#fff; 
        font-size:80%; 
        font-family: "trebuchet ms", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        /* hide overflow:hidden from IE5/Mac */ 
        /* \*/ 
        overflow: hidden; 
        /* */ 
    }

    body {height:100%; max-height:100%; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}

    #content {display:block; height:100%; max-height:100%; overflow:hidden; padding-left:0px; position:relative; z-index:3; word-wrap:break-word;}

    #head {position:absolute; margin:0; top:0; right:18px; display:block; width:100%; height:50px; background:#fff; font-size:1em; z-index:5; color:#000; border-bottom:1px solid #000;}

    #foot {position:absolute; margin:0; bottom:-1px; right:18px; display:block; width:100%; height:25px; background:#fff; color:#000; text-align:right; font-size:2em; z-index:4; border-top:1px solid #000;}

    .pad1 {display:block; width:18px; height:50px; float:left;}

    .pad2 {display:block; height:50px;}

    .pad3 {display:block; height:500px;}

    #content p {padding:5px;}

    .bold {font-size:1.2em; font-weight:bold;}

    .red {color:#c00; margin-left:5px; font-family:"trebuchet ms", "trebuchet", "verdana", sans-serif;}

    h2 {margin-left:5px;}

    h3 {margin-left:5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head">
    <div class="pad1"></div><h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="pad2"></div>
    <IFRAME name="teste" src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></IFRAME>
<!--<div class="pad3"></div>-->
</div>
<div id="foot">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can some one give me some clues about what can I do to solve this?

See image bellow, I'm testing with Firefox. I need that the scroll down is placed all across the webpage, and in this moment they skipp the header section.

[image]

Best Regards. (Edited)

Comment: Please elaborate more on the problem, do you mean that you don't want the footer to be fixed and you want it to be placed at the very end?

Comment: this scrollbar is the scrollbar of the iframe, so you can't make it to scroll the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

you set `height:100%` for the `iframe` and also you have z-index for the `footer`. So the iframe take the whole height but it's behind footer, so you can't see correct the scrollbar. Delete the `height="100%"` from `iframe` tag in your html code and then add in the `iframe` selector in your css code a fixed height, for example `height:500px;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done without either fixing the height of the iframe, or setting it to the height of it's content dynamically with javascript. If you could do that you could add padding top and bottom, then position your fixed elements on top.

As Sotiris said the scrollbar is on your iframe, you need the scrollbar to be on a container but without a fixed height on the iframe you can't make a container the right size to fit the header, iframe and footer inside.

Hope this makes sense.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;
        background:#fff;
        font-size:80%;
        font-family: "trebuchet ms", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #heading {
        padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;
        display: block; position: fixed;
        top: 0px; right: 16px;
        height: 50px; width: 100%;
        z-index: 60;
        background-color: #ddf;
    }
    #heading h1 {
        padding:5px; margin:0px 0px 0px 16px; border:0px;
    }

    #container {
        padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;
        display: block; position: fixed;
        top: 0px; left: 0px;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 50;
    }

    #footer {
        padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;
        display: block; position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px; right: 16px;
        height: 30px; width: 100%;
        z-index: 60;
        background-color: #ddf;
    }
    #footer p {
        padding:5px; margin:0px 0px 0px 16px; border:0px;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%; height: 2000px;
        border: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 30;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="heading"><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div style="height: 50px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <iframe name="test" src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
        <div style="height: 25px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```